# How to switch the player's sprite image in JavaScript/Kaboom.js

Tags: javascript, kaboom

So, I want to make a game where you need to take coins and be bigger, but when you take 4 coins I need to reset the player scale (Reset Player Scale is not a problem) and I need to switch the player image, the sprite for another, like a pass Level system. (and that is the problem) I just do it with JavaScript and I'm using kaboom.js and that my script:

```
import kaboom from "kaboom"

// initialize context
kaboom()

const speed = 150;
let PlayerScale = 1;
let limitcoins = 0;

// load assets
loadSprite("player", "sprites/bean.png")
loadSprite("coin", "sprites/coin.png");
loadSprite("player2", "sprites/bean2.png");

// Adicionar um sprite chamado "player"
const player = add([
  sprite("player"),
  pos(width() / 2, height() / 2),
  scale(PlayerScale),
  area(),
  "player" //tag do player pra deteção de colisão
]);

// Adicionar um sprite chamado "player2" com a tag "player2" e escala inicial de 0
const player2 = add([
  sprite("player2"),
  pos(width() / 2, height() / 2),
  scale(0),
  area(),
  "player2"
]);

// Function to spawn a new coin at a random position
function spawnCoin() {
  const spawnDistance = 400;
  const spawnX = player.pos.x + rand(-spawnDistance, spawnDistance);
  const spawnY = player.pos.y + rand(-spawnDistance, spawnDistance)
  const coin = add([
    sprite("coin"),
    pos(spawnX, spawnY),
    scale(0.5), // scale the sprite down by half
    area(),
  ]);

  // Detect collision with player
  coin.collides("player", (player) => {
    if (!coin.collided) {
      coin.collided = true; // desativa a detecção de colisão
      destroy(coin);
      PlayerScale += 1; // increase player scale
      player.scale = PlayerScale; // update player scale


// Definir a posição da câmera com base na posição do jogador
player.action(() => {
  camPos(player.pos);
});

// Spawn the initial coin
setInterval(() => {
  spawnCoin();
  limitcoins += 1;
}, 1000);



// Mover o sprite com as teclas W, A, S e D
keyDown("w", () => {
  player.move(0, -speed);
});

keyDown("a", () => {
  player.move(-speed, 0);
});

keyDown("s", () => {
  player.move(0, speed);
});

keyDown("d", () => {
  player.move(speed, 0);
});
```

Sorry I know my english sucks

I don't know how to make it but I tried that:

```
      // Trocar o sprite do jogador se playerScale for igual a 4
      if (playerScale === 4) {
        player.swap("player2");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

I don't know if that player.swap script is good, so if it sucks will be better a script made from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

In order to switch the player's sprite, you can use: `player.use(sprite('player2'))`
or just create a sprite sheet for your player.

Example on sprite sheets:
https://kaboomjs.com/play?demo=sprite